# Python/Pyglet on linux, script exits immediately

Tags: python, linux, pyglet

I am trying to start programming with pyglet on my lubuntu laptop. The script exits immediately. 
It shows a black window that disappears within 1 second. I don't see any errors.
Am I doing anything wrong or is there any additional software that needs to be installed.

I tried 3 scripts that I scavenged from the internet. 
The second is similar to the first, I removed the Microsoft font line.
Also replacing "Times New Roman" with "Ubuntu", an installed linux font, does not make a difference.

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
pyglet.app.run()

################################################################

import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
pyglet.app.run()

###############################################################3

import pyglet
class HelloWorldWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HelloWorldWindow, self).__init__()
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world!')
    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.label.draw()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = HelloWorldWindow()
pyglet.app.run()
```

The python shell window shows the same output on each of the attempts:

```
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160914] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
========== RESTART: /home/hennep/Desktop/pyglet/hello.py ==========

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>>
```

The next snippet works without the commented line. When I uncomment the line, same problem
So I am unable to use pyglet.text.Label.

```
import pyglet  
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=320, height=200,caption='window')  
#label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world')  
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Rather than "scripts scavenged from the internet", have you tried running any of the examples included with pyglet itself?

Comment: `window.clear()`: Clear the window.

Comment: import pyglet
    window = pyglet.window.Window(width=320,  height=200,caption='window')
    #label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world')
    pyglet.app.run()

This works without the commented line.
When I uncomment the line, same problem

Comment: readers don't need to know the whole history. If your `edit` at the end defines the problem, then you have successfully created a [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and  you should reedit your Q to remove unnecessary info. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was probably caused by the 64 bit OS.
Yesterday I tried one of the scripts on a Debian 32 bit clean install and it worked fine.
Today I ran the same script on a freshly installed Debian 64 bit Pc. It failed again, the same way as my Intel Core I5 laptop with Lubuntu.

It's not statistically correct to blame 64bit already but if someone else stumbles on this thread with the same problem. Try 32 bits.
For me it is an acceptable workaround.